# Xcorr function in python for acceleration signal

Tags: signals, correlation, shift, acceleration

I have two acceleration signals with different lengths, whose start and end times are not the same. I want to find the time difference between these two from the initial data and the end in seconds and correct the signal. The first signal has 434915 samples and the second signal has 398303 samples, the sampling rate of each signal is 200 Hz.